# Saving xDocument after delete a element in Windows Store Application (Windows 8 Metro)

Tags: c#, xml, windows-8, linq-to-xml, windows-store-apps

at first I want to be mentioned again my platform is **windows store application** (because some users think I talking about desktop environment and close my question as a duplicated topic). I have a xml document and I delete a element by following method:

```
public async void DeleteDocument(Word deletedItem)
{
   StorageFile storageFile = await _fileloc.StorageFile();
   var file = await storageFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);
   Stream inStream = file.AsStreamForWrite();
   XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(inStream);
   xDoc.Descendants("Word").Single(p =>((Guid)p.Element("Id")).Equals(deletedItem.Id)).Remove();
   xDoc.Save(inStream);   
}
```

the element deleted successfully but when I save the xDocument , the new xDocument is appended in the end xml file like this

```
<XML ....>
<Word id="1">
     <Item x="...."/>
     <Item x="...."/>
</Word>
<Word id="2">
     <Item x="...."/>
     <Item x="...."/>
</Word>
</XML><XML ....>
<Word Id="2">
    <Item x="...."/>
     <Item x="...."/>
</Word>
</XML>
```

please advice me and thanks for ur help.

Update:

after Jim O'Neil advice the saved document is like

```
<XML ....>
<Word id="1">
     <Item x="...."/>
     <Item x="...."/>
</Word>
 x="...."/>
     <Item x="...."/>
</Word>
</XML>
```

Answer (score 0):

You've opened the file for read/write access and when you load the XML, the file pointer is now at the end of the file.  So when you save it starts writing wherever the file pointer is - at the end of the file.

See if this works better:

```
var file = await storageFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);
using (Stream inStream = file.AsStreamForWrite())
{
    XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(inStream);
    xDoc.Descendants("word").Remove();
    inStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    xDoc.Save(inStream);
    await inStream.FlushAsync();
}
```

it's not precisely your code (I couldn't get the call to Single to compile), but you can see the pattern; namely the call to [Seek](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.seek%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: I don't understand? I see you updated the XML to match your code looking for "Word", but that wasn't the 'important' part.  Is it working now with the call to Seek?